# Should concrete stair landing be anchored to building?

Tags: concrete, masonry

I have a small, approximately 3x3' concrete landing in front of my basement door, from which stairs go up to the street level. I need to redo it and was wondering whether to tie the rebar from under the slab to bolt anchors I can set into the foundation footing of the house that it is attached to.  I can think of reason pro and con both.

E.g. I think anchoring it would make it firmer combined with the building and resisting breakage from ground movements (e.g. nearby drainage) to a certain degree but at the same time, if it does exceed that point it might be better not to be tied to induce breakage along the contact line where the slab meets the building and not some other point (if my line of thinking is right, please correct me if wrong).

I was thinking to drill 3-4 anchor holes in the foundation using my hammer drill, set led anchors and drive some bolts, then tie the rebar from under the slab to it using chicken wire.

Comment: Are the stairs only meeting the pad or do they run along the building?

Comment: I regularly tie small slabs to the foundation. You don't have to use anchors  if you drill you holes at angles like- / \  / \ /  \ - you can use 20 penny galvanized nails the angles keep it from moving away and from settling.

Comment: @EdBeal - sounds like an answer - and yes if you can concrete stairs should always be tied to the building.  I hate when I see a perfectly good set of stairs that have pulled away 3-4 inches but otherwise are great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok guess I need to put as an answer thanks @DMoore. I regularly tie small slabs to the foundation. You don't have to use anchors if you drill you holes at angles like- / \ / \ / \ - you can use 20 penny galvanized nails the angles keep it from moving away and from settling